# Android Studio - Creating a simple timetable

Tags: android, android-studio

I am currently developing an application, and I want to add a timetable to it, similar to this, http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/dd/dnd3.php, where I can add values (classes, such as Biology etc.) to a HTML timetable with days Mon-Fri, and times on the side (e.g. 8:05am - 9:05am), although I cant find any tutorials to this as I am new to programming.

How would I do this?

Cheers!

Edit: here is my code. https://github.com/soc0t/EPQTestingNotWorking

Comment: Android supports table layouts, have you tried looking into that?

Comment: how does this question is related to android or android studio ?

Answer (score 1):

> try this hope work..... Biology

```
            <tr>
                <td><div class="item">English</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div class="item">Science</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div class="item">Music</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div class="item">History</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div class="item">Computer</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div class="item">Mathematics</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div class="item">Arts</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div class="item">Ethics</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div class="item">Biology</div></td>
            </tr>
```

> this is for (8:05am-9:05am)

```
            <tr>
                <td class="blank"></td>
                <td class="title">Monday</td>
                <td class="title">Tuesday</td>
                <td class="title">Wednesday</td>
                <td class="title">Thursday</td>
                <td class="title">Friday</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="time">08:00</td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="time">08:05</td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="time">09:05</td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="time">09:00</td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="time">10:00</td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="time">11:00</td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="time">12:00</td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="time">13:00</td>
                <td class="lunch" colspan="5">Lunch</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="time">14:00</td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="time">15:00</td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="time">16:00</td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
                <td class="drop"></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: How do I insert this into android studio? would it go in the .xml file? or do I need to tell android studio that I am inputting html?

Comment: create assets folder...right click on >> app >> new >> folder >> assets folder.... then paste ur html file

Answer (score 0):

create assets folder...right click on >> app >> new >> folder >> assets folder.... then paste ur html file....

> in xml file

```
   <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

> in MainActivity

```
                                                                                                                                                                                                 WebView mWebView = null;
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/new.html");
```

Comment: This causes the activity to crash and close the app, I get this error in the logcat   http://pastebin.com/53gebpM4

Comment: Here you go, Logcat included in the README.  https://github.com/soc0t/EPQTestingNotWorking